# How to pass value from a cell to a userform label in vba6

Tags: excel, vba

I have stripped down my code to bare in order to find my problem. This is to read from a cell into a label (PartInformation) on a UserForm. I can make it work using a string but when I change over to reading from a cell, I get error "1004 Application defined" or "User defined error". I even use this to read `Now()` to the UserForm and that works. Please help me understand where I am going wrong. Thanks for helping me.

```
Private Sub OkayCommandButton_Click()
    Worksheets("Parts List").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("A2").Select
    Cells.find(What:="34300TMA010", After:=Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    'this does not work
    PartInformation = Worksheets("Parts List").Range(ActiveCell)
    'this works
    PartInformation = "yes"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `ActiveCell` is not a valid parameter for `Range`. With `Range`, you are trying to get a cell but you might already have it just with `ActiveCell`. Try this:

```
PartInformation = ActiveCell
```

Comment: @jimneely I'll explain further because you stated you didn't know why this was working. This code is equivalent to PartInformation.Caption = ActiveCell.Value because when you don't supply a property (.Caption and .Value in this case) VBA is using the default properties, which happen to be these two.

Comment: @jimneely Also, your Cell.Find line of code has a ".Activate" at the end. That made the found cell "active" and ActiveCell is an easy way to just refer to that cell.

Comment: @jimneely Is there anything else you need? If not, can I convince you to accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** This works for me.

```
Private Sub OkayCommandButton_Click()
    ' ...your other code...
    UserForm1.PartInformation.Caption = ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```

[image]

**Explanation:** The property of a label that contains its visible text is `.Caption`. So if you want to change the text, you need to change that property, not just the Label element itself. Likewise, the value of a cell is accessed using the `.Value` property.

(By the way, `ActiveCell` is an application level object, not sheet level. Hence `Sheets("sheet name").ActiveCell` will not work. [Link for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834673.aspx). `.Range` expects an address, such as "$A$12" but you are specifying the cell object, not its address. A correct way could be `PartInformation.Caption = Worksheets("Parts List").Range(ActiveCell.Address).Value`)

Comment: This works as well. What the heck... I guess all I needed to do was add the .Address. Thanks a million!!

Comment: Yes you can do that but it's a bit like saying "my mother's mother's daughter is my mother" :-) that's why I proposed an easier one. ;-)